# Query rosparam for public/private status

Tags: rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can the rosparam command line tool tell me whether a parameter is private or public? If so, how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269118/query-rosparam-for-public/private-status/) by [dinosaur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21732/dinosaur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 233 on 2017-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"Private" parameters aren't really "private." The concept of private parameters is just useful for bookkeeping. The "private" namespace of a node is just the namespace that has the same path as the node. The parameter server doesn't hide private parameters from other nodes.

You could, perhaps, infer that a parameter is private if there exists a node whose ROS graph path is a prefix of the parameter. However, this would be prone to errors. For example, the following launch file is valid:

```
<launch>
<node name="my_node" pkg="my_pkg" type="my_exe" />
<group ns="my_node">
    <param name="my_private_param" value="foo"/>
    <node name="my_inception_node" pkg="my_pkg" type="my_other_exe">
        <param name="my_super_private_param" value="foo"/>
    </node>
</group>
<node name="another_node" pkg="my_pkg" type="yet_another_exe"/>
</launch>
```

The parameter `/my_node/my_private_param` is private to `/my_node`, but it's public to `/my_node/my_inception_node`. Even `/another_node` can see that parameter by querying the fully-qualified path, i.e. `/my_node/my_private_param`.

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-19**:
While there is no explicit hiding, I don't believe that you can say that:

> parameter `/my_node/my_private_param` is private to `/my_node`, but it's public to `/my_node/my_inception_node`.

private parameters are private to the node by definition. The fact that `my_inception_node` lives in the ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-19**:
.. same namespace doesn't change that fact.

If you create a private `NodeHandle` in `my_inception_node`, it will (should) not be able to find `my_private_param`.

**Comment by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) on 2017-08-19**:
My point is that there is such a thing as a private `NodeHandle`, but no such thing as a private parameter. You can create a `NodeHandle` scoped to any namespace you like. A private `NodeHandle` is just a special case where you create a `NodeHandle` scoped to the path of the node.

**Comment by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) on 2017-08-19**:
You're correct that a private `NodeHandle` in `my_inception_node` can't find `/my_node/my_private_param`. That's what I meant when I called it "public" in that context.